# How to do a random search in vi editor?

Tags: search, vi

By random, I mean neither from top, nor from middle, nor from bootom. The search should return randomly ordered results.

eg: I am searching for "failed" in vi editor. I want randomly ordered results.

And when I press n or N(or any other key), I should get randomly ordered messages.

Comment: not saying this is off-topic here (I think it's on-topic!), but the [Vi and Vim Stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) sister site might have more experience in implementing esoteric things in vim. You, however, say "vi". Are we really talking about the original vi? that would be severely limiting. Or are we talking about vim in vi backwards compatibility, or BSD's nvi?

Comment: vi. I really mean vi.

Comment: By the way, depending on what you actually need, you will have to define "randomly ordered" better. Even assuming "random" means "independent" (which it doesn't, it's just a commonly made mistake) It makes a big difference if you say "from the set of all matches, pressing `n` should select any one with equal probability" or, "from the set of all regions in the file, `n` should pick the next one at with equal probability, and repeat until it hits a match", because in the first case, regions in the file with few matches will be hit very rarely, and in the second case,

Comment: matches in regions with high match density will be hit less often. Or are you really looking for a random permutation of the list of results? (say, having k results) Because that means pressing `n` cycles through the results in a fixed order. Once you seen all k, you jump back to the start of the sequence. But what if you change the file, add a match?

Comment: @achhainsan "I really mean v" doesn't mean anything. _Which_ vi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to find a random match would be to do the search once, and then type a random number and press either `n` or `N` (randomly?).  This will work in any vi variant.

An extremely simplistic pseudo random number generator is to pick a *M* for *N* items where M and N are mutually prime, select a "random" start value (S) , and then (S+M)%N is the next value.  Typically you want M larger than N.  If there is a common factor between N and M, then you get a cycle that may not cover all possible items.  For best performance, M should be between N/2 and 3N/2.

So, for extra bonus, you could select a moderately large prime number (possibly larger than your guess of number of matches) and assign that followed by `n` to an alias key in vi.  This will give you a command that will "randomly" cycle through all matches.